# Глаголы совершенного и несовершенного вида

Tags: грамматика

Можно ли иностранцам давать глаголы совершенного и несовершенного вида в самом начале обучения?

Answer (score 1):

Я не знаю, что там говорят методики РКИ - и вообще перподаватели.
Но мое понимание: вопрос не "нужно ли давать", а "как давать".
Иностранцы путаются не в грамматике, а в ситуации - когда что употребляется...
"Я изучил русский язык" и я "изучал русский язык". Ну как ему объяснить, в чем разница, не разбирая в деталях каждую ситуацию отдельно?! Он-то уверен, что он именно изучил. Т.е. прошел курс. Это из недавно зафиксированного. Как не давать-то?!

Если реально хотите обсудить, есть специальные форумы - и менее специальные, но более душевные.
Я бы из последних порекомендовал "Грамоту", но с оговоркой, что там сейчас сильно лихорадит... И регистрация сложная.
http://newforum.gramota.ru/

Но если надо обсудить в диалоге, деталях, - попробуйте. Там еще не перевелись РКИшники.

Answer (score 1):

У них вместо совершенного /несовершенного вида - аспект. Что отчасти совпадает с русским с/н видом. Для иностранцев это не самое сложное.